# How can I solve this differential equation using specific method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following problem:

$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t} + y - (\epsilon)y^2 = 0\ \ \ \ \text{for}\ \  t \geq 0, y(0) = 2$$

a) Compute an approximate solution by substitution method:
 $y(t) = y_0(t) + \epsilon\ y_1(t) + \epsilon^2y_2(t) + \ldots \text{up to the order}\  \epsilon^2$;

b) Guess the term of order $\epsilon^n$ in the approximate solution using same substitution method;

I know how to find an exact solution, but I have hard time using such substitution method to approximate the exact solution. Any help?

Comment: You are simply supposed to solve $$y'_0(x)+\epsilon y'_1(x)+\epsilon^2y'_2(x)+o(\epsilon^2)+y_0(x)+\epsilon y_1(x)+\epsilon^2y_2(x)+o(\epsilon^2)-\epsilon(y_0(x)+\epsilon y_1(x)+o(\epsilon))^2=0$$ that is, $$y'_0(x)+\epsilon y'_1(x)+\epsilon^2y'_2(x)+y_0(x)+\epsilon y_1(x)+\epsilon^2y_2(x)-\epsilon y_0^2(x)-2\epsilon^2y_0(x) y_1(x)=0$$ that is, $$y'_0(x)+y_0(x)=y'_1(x)+y_1(x)-y_0(x)^2=y'_2(x)+y_2(x)-2y_0(x) y_1(x)=0$$ Can you continue?

Comment: I went to that far... but I couldn't continue from there.... T.T

Comment: Can you solve this for $y_0(x)$? (Sidenote: If indeed you "went that far" this should have been mentioned in the question.)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention it....
$y_0(x) = 2e^(-t)$ This is what I got for $y_0(x)$ How can I then solve for $y_1(x)$? I don't know the initial conditions for it

Comment: Try $y_0(0)=2$, $y_1(0)=y_2(0)=0$.

Comment: how about initial point for $y'_0(0) and y''_0(0)$ ?

Comment: You do not need them, do you?

Comment: Don't I need them to find $y_1(t)$?

Comment: Yes you want $y_1(t)$ and you do not need $y'_0(0)$ and $y''_0(0)$ for that.

Comment: ah!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I got it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!

Comment: You might want to post an answer yourself?